# How can I rotate my picture using Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make the Dragon on the picture rotate softly to the left when he flies to the left and rotate to the right when he flies to the right and up and down also.

[image]

How can I do that with the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys? The Dragon can fly already up, down, lef, and right....but he doesn't turn...

My Code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1600, 848
speed = [2, 2]
black = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.broken_x)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
background = pygame.image.load("background.PNG")
dragon1 = pygame.image.load("dragon1.gif")
x,y=0,0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
speed=250
movex, movey=0,0

while True:
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
screen.blit(dragon1, (x,y))

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

if event.type==KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_a:
            movex=-4
        elif event.key==K_d:
            movex=+4
        elif event.key==K_w:
            movey=-4
        elif event.key==K_s:
            movey=+4
if event.type==KEYUP:
        if event.key==K_a:
            movex=0
        elif event.key==K_d:
            movex=0
        elif event.key==K_w:
            movey=0
        elif event.key==K_s:
            movey=0
x+=movex
y+=movey

pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: So that the dragon looks to the left when he flys to the left.

Comment: In the future, please *do not* delete and re-post your question. Just edit it.

Comment: but then no-one sees my question....can you help me now?

Comment: Everybody still sees your question, because you edited it, which moves it to the front page. Trying to circumvent the rules of the site, however, is a great way to guarantee your questions *don't* get viewed because they get closed. Please read the [help] so you don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: ok sorry :) thx i never make this mistake again...

Comment: Please accept an answer if your question is solved. Do *not* edit the word "solved" into your title. Please read the [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pygame.transform.rotate` function:

```
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    angle = None
    if movex == 0 and movey < 0:
        angle = -180
    elif movex > 0 and movey >= 0:
        angle = 20
    elif movex < 0 and movey >= 0:
        angle = -20
    elif movex > 0 and movey < 0:
        angle = 160
    elif movex < 0 and movey < 0:
        angle = -160

    if angle:
        dragon = pygame.transform.rotate(dragon1, angle)
    else:
        dragon = dragon1

    screen.blit(dragon, (x,y))
    ...
```

You can always keep the original surface `dragon1` and transform it when you are going to blit it (like the example), or keep three variations pre-calculated and choose which one you want to blit.

Comment: sorry i'm just beginner but i tried it an it doesn't work...like your example..

Comment: and what when de dragon flys up and down?

Comment: now it works but the dragon turns all the time i hold the key down...:(

Comment: Isn't it good? That while you are going right the angle is always the same? I'll add code for up and down too.

Comment: sorry what? if the dragon fly's left, he turns 20* but all the time until im stop holding the key...but he should turn only once he flys on one side...

Comment: Do you mean now it keeps rotating doing full 360° rotations? If so you are assigning `dragon1` instead of `dragon`.

Comment: and i had that idea with the 3 or 4 variations of the dragon too but i think i double, tripple, or blit it 4 times when i do this because the normal blit is also in the loop

Comment: yes but if i asing it as dragon it doesn't work...

Comment: sorry for my english...im swiss

Comment: Assing to `dragon` then blit `dragon`, just like the code.

Comment: ok i test it again...

Comment: ah sorry i didn't saw that you edited your answer...

Comment: invalid syntax ... after elif is the ":" red

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typo, it's corrected now.

Comment: ok everthing is up-side-down but thx man!